# How to implement Services in Xamarin Forms app?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want to implement services that run even if the app is closed, I have used that kind of services in Android with java, but I haven't found documentation of services in the multiplatform app. Is there any nugget, documentation or something to help me to do that?

Comment: google "xamarin forms background"

Comment: I was asking for an example

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Comment: you could refer to the [official document](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground)

Comment: Gracias @LeoZhu-MSFT , pero busco para xamarin forms, para Android si he utilizado.

Comment: yes,xamarin forms is similar to this,here is for forms[foreground service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services)

Comment: And how to do it for both platforms? Is there a wrapper?

Comment: I don't know much about ios, but it seems that ios can't keep the service running after the app is closed.

Comment: So how do I handle downloading and uploading files on IOS with multiplatform xamarin app.

Comment: you could use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/),write the downloading and uploading method in .ios project，then use DependencyService call it